# Get return code from Perl script and hide from process table

Tags: perl

I have a script that calls a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file:

```
exec("$java_path/java -jar testjar.jar --username user --password pswd");
```

or

```
system("$java_path/java -jar testjar.jar --username user -password pswd");
```

I need to return the error code from the JAR file. `Exec` does this on Linux, but not on Windows. This seems to be a bug in Perl... I found it in Stack Overflow question *[Return code using exec is not coming back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617420/return-code-using-exec-not-coming-back)*.

I started using exec, but after getting the answer from that Stack Overflow question I started using the workaround posted by ikegami. However, now my issue is that when using `system` the process is in the process table with the arguments showing (the main issue being the password).

I am looking for a solution where I can both get the return code and hide the password from the process table.

Answer (score 1):

Processes can only change the way their own arguments appear — the arguments of other processes are off limits. You will need to pass the password to your Java application in some way other than as a command-line argument.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I gave enough information the first time.  I do not believe that type of solution will work.  When I run the system command, the Perl script will also stay in the process table the whole time.

The password / username arguments are being passed by another program to my perl script.  I have no access to the code of that program.  So I am stuck with the args being passed to my perl script via command line.